# Chrome Extension - background page form submission using messaging. Form submitting only once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am having an issue with messaging in my chrome extension. I am passing a message from a content script to a background page/javascript. My background page has a form. As part of my background.js I am completing some input fields and then submitting the form.

This all appears to be working the first time I load up my chrome extension. My background form is submitted. However, I am not getting a success message in the console for my content script any subsequent message from the content script results in an error being logged in the console. The error message it "Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined".

I have noticed that if I comment the form submit line from my background javascript there is no problem with submitting multiple messages. This points to the form submit causing the problem. I can not work out, however, what the problem may be. Any help would be very much appreciated.

A snip of my content script, logging the message:

```
 var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(presetText);
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
hiddenElement.download = fileName+'.lrtemplate';
hiddenElement.click();
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({filename: fileName, preset:presetText}, function(response) {
console.log(response.message);
});
```

My background page:

```
<head>
<!-- ©snow monkey lab
snowmonkeylab@gmail.com-->
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" id="trackMe">
<input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D7F000000xRQ5">
<label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text"/><br>
<label for="company">Company</label><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" /><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

My background javascript:

```
    function submitForm() {
document.getElementById("trackMe").reset();
document.getElementById("trackMe").submit();
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
console.log(request);
document.getElementById("last_name").value=request.filename;
submitForm();
sendResponse({message: "success"});
return true;
});
```

Comment: Is there  a particular reason you are sending the "background page" data in a HTML form rather then an AJAX request?

Comment: @gearold - I am actually using a web to lead form from salesforce (standard html form) to submit my data to a salesforce database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form has the target attribute set to `"_self"` by default, so submitting the form makes the background page load the result from the server.

You can set `target="_blank"` but that will open a new tab on each form submit.
Alternatively, the form target can be set to name an iframe in the page, and it will load there. Basically like this:

Add an iframe to your background html:

```
<iframe name="my_iframe"></iframe>
```

And add the target attribute to your form to reference the iframe

```
<form target="my_iframe" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" id="trackMe">
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code and the issue is the html form. When you manually submit a html form it will redirect to the "action" of the form. This explains why it works the first time and not any time after.

Use the fetch api to make the post request, this way you will not be redirected.

Here is an example:

```
fetch('https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      {
        last_name: 'your last name',
        company: 'your company',
        oid: '00D7F000000xRQ5'
      }
    })
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log('Returned data:', data);
  });
```

Adjust the body object to what is required to simulate the html form